# Is there a way to make <menu> a prefix key in emacs?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I'm trying to get `vimish-fold` to work, and it does work. The problem is that I want to bind it to the `menu` key instead of the `M` key.

```
(progn
    (define-prefix-command 'my-menu-key-map)
    (define-key vimish-fold-mode (kdb "v f") 'vimish-fold)
    (define-key vimish-fold-mode (kdb "v u") 'vimish-fold-refold)
)

(global-set-key (kdb "<menu>") my-menu-key-map)
```

I essentially want `menu v f` -> `vimish-fold` and `menu v u` -> `vimish-fold-refold`. The problem I'm having is it's giving me an error telling me I have the wrong type argument.

```
Error in private config: init.el, (wrong-type-argument keymapp nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some repeated typos:

1. `(kdb` should be `(kbd`
2. `(define-key vimish-fold-mode` should be `(define-key my-menu-key-map`